Can't build huffman tree in C, qsort fails
I try to implement huffman code in C. I have two arrays, one storing all the nodes and one that contains pointers to certain nodes. The second one contains the unfinished trees that I want to combine. I have to sort the trees to combine the two with the lowest frequency, but qsort() fails with a segfault. In there I try to compare the frequency member of my tree struct but that fails. When I try to access the frequency member outside of my compare function it works. (relevant part is the compareFrequeny function and the last while loop in huffman.c)
main.c:
#include "huffman.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* inputP = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE* outputP = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if (!(inputP && outputP)) return 1;

    encode(inputP, outputP);

    fclose(inputP);
    fclose(outputP);
    return 0;
}


huffman.h:
#ifndef HUFFMAN_H
#define HUFFMAN_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node node;

// static int compareFrequency(const void* a, const void* b);
void encode(FILE* input, FILE* output);

#endif


huffman.c:
#include "huffman.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    node* left;
    node* right;
    unsigned int frequency;
    char* bytes;
};

static int compareFrequency(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    // Sort by frequency (higher first) or if equal by tree size (bigger first, only educated guess)
    if (((node*)a)->frequency < ((node*)b)->frequency) return 1;
    if (((node*)a)->frequency > ((node*)b)->frequency) return -1;
    if (strlen(((node*)a)->bytes) < strlen(((node*)b)->bytes)) return 1;
    if (strlen(((node*)a)->bytes) > strlen(((node*)b)->bytes)) return -1;
    return 0;
}

void encode(FILE* input, FILE* output)
{
    unsigned int possibleBytes[256] = { 0 }, differentTrees = 0, i;
    char currChar;

    // Count number of occurence of each individual byte
    while ((currChar = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        possibleBytes[currChar]++;
    }

    // Count number of different bytes
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (possibleBytes[i]) differentTrees++;
    }

    // Make array filled with used bytes and their absolute frequency
    node* nodes = calloc(differentTrees * 2 - 1, sizeof(node));
    node* nodesP = nodes;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (possibleBytes[i]) {
            nodesP->bytes = calloc(2, sizeof(char));
            *nodesP->bytes = i;
            *(nodesP->bytes + 1) = '\0';
            nodesP->frequency = possibleBytes[i];
            nodesP++;
        }
    }

    // Fill trees array with nodes
    node** trees = calloc(differentTrees, sizeof(node*));
    // for (i = 0; i < differentTrees; i++) {
    //     printf("%c: %d\n", *(nodes + i)->bytes, (nodes + i)->frequency);
    // }

    node** treesP = trees;
    nodesP = nodes;
    for (i = 0; i < differentTrees; i++) {
        *treesP = nodesP;
        treesP++;
        nodesP++;
    }

    // Build tree
    node* lastTree;
    node* secondLastTree;

    while (differentTrees > 1) {
        lastTree = *trees + differentTrees - 1;
        secondLastTree = *trees + differentTrees - 2;
        // printf("%d\n", differentTrees);
        // printf("%p\n", nodesP);
        // printf("%p\n\n", lastTree);
        nodesP->left = lastTree;
        nodesP->right = secondLastTree;
        nodesP->frequency = lastTree->frequency + secondLastTree->frequency;
        nodesP->bytes
            = calloc(strlen(lastTree->bytes) + strlen(secondLastTree->bytes) + 1, sizeof(char));
        strcat(nodesP->bytes, lastTree->bytes);
        strcat(nodesP->bytes, secondLastTree->bytes);
        secondLastTree = nodesP;

        printf("%s\n", secondLastTree->bytes);
        differentTrees--;
        nodesP++;

        printf("%u\n\n", secondLastTree->frequency);
        qsort(*trees, differentTrees, sizeof(node*), &compareFrequency);
    }
}


Makefile:
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
OBJ = main.o huffman.o

huffman: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<


clean:
    rm *.o


I tried debugging my code using gdb.
I expect to not get a segfault

You have another issue with:
    char currChar;
    ...
        possibleBytes[currChar]++;

currChar is signed, so if the byte is 128 or more, you will have a negative index. That would be an out-of-bounds access of possibleBytes. It should be:
    int currChar;
    ...
        possibleBytes[currChar]++;

Also your first combination of nodes is on an unsorted array, so they are likely not the two smallest frequency nodes. You need to do the sort first.
